# Jenkins thinBackup scheduled backup is not running

Tags: jenkins

I have installed **thinBackup plugin** to back up my Jenkins, and I have configured it as follows:

[image]

So, there should be a full backup everyday after 08:00 PM, unfortunately for some reason, the scheduled backups are not running at all.

But, manual backup (by clicking the **Backup Now** button in the main page) works:

[image]

Jenkins has write access to the backup directory.

Can anyone let me know what could be the problem here?

FYI: I got the same problem with **Periodic Backup plugin** as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked Jenkins log is there anything weird?

Comment: Also tried out backup scheduled with corn like formate it should work

Comment: There is any job running when you try to do the backup?

Comment: I'm sure there are no jobs running when backup is scheduled. I also tried other valid corn format values like **H 9 * * 1-5** and **30 9 * * 1-5** etc., nothing seems to work. I checked the logs folder **C:\Users\Jenkins\.jenkins\logs\tasks\**, and I see only one log file **Workspace clean-up.log** created at the time of scheduled full backup. This log file contains:

Comment: **Started at Mon Jul 16 20:38:32 CEST 2018<eol>
Checking Job_Name_1<eol>
Checking Job_Name_2<eol>
Finished at Mon Jul 16 20:38:32 CEST 2018. 159ms<eol>
Started at Tue Jul 17 20:38:32 CEST 2018<eol>
Checking Job_Name_1<eol>
Checking Job_Name_2<eol>
Finished at Tue Jul 17 20:38:32 CEST 2018. 149ms**

<eol> here means end of line.

Looks like it is just trying to clear workspace of all jobs (including disabled), which were already cleared before (clearing workspace is part of each job).

Don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: Do you have a delta between backup time set and real launch time? As if thinBackup (not jenkins) was on GMT+8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem, restarting Jenkins worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. Restarting Jenkins worked for me as well.